# Obtain a State Space System given Denavit-Hartenberg parameters and a Rigid Body Tree model in MATLAB

Tags: control, robotic-arm, dh-parameters

I'm confused regarding the representatoin of a 6 D.O.F. robot arm with multiple links. I have the denavit-Hartenberg parameters and have used these to create a Rigid Body Tree model in MATLAB. The model works perfectly in MATLAB and is capable of tracking a trajectory in Task Space. The next step is to implement a Model Predictive Controller. But in order to a apply a Model Predictive Control sheme I need the state space representation.

How can i get from the Denavit-Hartenberg parameters to a state space representation?

Comment: You can define states as the parameters that you want to control . In the robot arm case , the states usually contain the joint variables and velocities . If you want to do MPC on a robot arm , I would worry more about defining the error functions.  Defining states is easy.